# C# : generate SQL script from database containing "use master"

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I'm working on a little tool that lets you generate the SQL script of an existing database. The script is generated without any problems, but when testing the script by executing it in SQL Server Management Studio, there is an error stating that the object name of one of my tables is invalid.

So I generated the script manually and the only difference was the very beginning of the script. The script that my tool created contains the line `use ClientND`, whereas the script that was created manually contains `use master`.

Because of this, I think this is the source of the error, so I tried to find a appropiate option in the ScriptingOptions, but with no avail.

Is there a way to include `use master` instead of `use dbName`?

Code:

```
public void GenerateSQLScripts(string dbName)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Server server = new Server(SqlServer);
    Database db = server.Databases[dbName];

    var scriptopt = new ScriptingOptions();
    scriptopt.TargetServerVersion = SqlServerVersion.Version105; // Windows 2008 R2
    scriptopt.AnsiPadding = true;
    scriptopt.WithDependencies = true;
    scriptopt.IncludeHeaders = true;
    scriptopt.SchemaQualify = true;
    scriptopt.ExtendedProperties = true;
    scriptopt.TargetDatabaseEngineType = DatabaseEngineType.Standalone;
    scriptopt.IncludeDatabaseContext = true;
    scriptopt.ScriptDrops = false;
    scriptopt.ScriptData = false;
    scriptopt.ScriptSchema = true;
    scriptopt.DriAllConstraints = true;
    scriptopt.DriForeignKeys = true;
    scriptopt.Indexes = true;
    scriptopt.DriPrimaryKey = true;
    scriptopt.DriUniqueKeys = true;
    scriptopt.DriChecks = true;
    scriptopt.AllowSystemObjects = false;
    scriptopt.AppendToFile = false;

    // script Tables
    foreach (Table t in db.Tables)
    {
        StringCollection sc = t.Script(scriptopt);

        foreach (string s in sc)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(s);
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I assume manually using Replace is unacceptable?

Comment: @Davesoft That would suffice, but I would have hoped for a more "elegant" solution.

Comment: I presume the connection string you are using to generate this script has a default schema?  Try using a connection string that has a default schema of master.

Comment: @Neil There is no connection string since I used Smo to connect to my local SQL Server. The only thing needed is the name of the instance of my SQL Server, ie. XXXXXXX\SQLEXPRESS. This name is passed to "Server server = new Server(SqlServer);"

Comment: If you tried your code on a full, properly set up, MS-SQL then perhaps the schema would be correct.

Comment: @Scorch in that case maybe it would be affected by the "default database" setting of the user you're connecting as? Just a guess, but worth checking.